# Why do I get a cors error when parsing an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, cross-domain, swr

Hi I am currently working on an app that's setting items in localStorage then later retrieve all items. When retrieving I am parsing the object to convert it from a stringified object to an object. On doing that I am getting this error,
**Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development.**

I tried to look for solutions but the one that's suggested is to clear local storage but It's a problem because I'll have to do that each time I press my button. Is there a fix for this.

My code:

```js
// This function gets all items from the local storage
  function getAll() {
    var values = [],
      keys = Object.keys(localStorage),
      i = keys.length;

    while (i--) {
      values.push(localStorage.getItem(keys[i]));
    }
    
    return values;
  }

  const getMissions = getAll();
  // This variable stores the parsed value, ie, turning a stringified object back to an object value
  const { image, missionName } = JSON.parse(getMissions);
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: what line does the CORS refering to?

Comment: `getMissions` is not a JSON object, it is an array. Try copy pasting `getAll`'s code in console and call it; you'll see